# Java error "overridden method does not throw java.io.IOException"?

Tags: java, sockets

This may be a very newbie question, but Is there a way to start a thread that creates sockets? Because I can't do the  following:

```
public void run() throws IOException{

  Socket sock2 = new Socket("localhost", 9898);


}
```

and I get this error:

> run() in CapitalizeClient cannot implement run() in
>   java.lang.Runnable   overridden method does not throw
>   java.io.IOException

Or should I just  create the socket code in the main? I'd like to periodically create sockets to use as a heartbeat. thanks

Comment: Or you could, you know, catch the exception.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot put `throws IOException` in the `run` method because the [`Runnable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) interface does not say that the `run` method throws any checked exceptions.

Either handle the `IOException` by catching it, or move the code to another location.

Comment: Thank You Very Much rgettman, now it's adding up. I put in the  try-catch and it worked